# In Android, how to render a video with Filters by VidEffects

Tags: java, android, video, effects

I can successfully apply filters to a recorded video in my app by using VidEffects (https://github.com/krazykira/VidEffects). The problem is that such plugin doesn't render a filtered video, anyway I'm trying to apply permanent video effects by using this class:

```
public class VideoProcessing extends AsyncTask {
    private final File myDirectory;
    private FFmpegFrameGrabber VIDEO_GRABBER;
    private FFmpegFrameRecorder videoRecorder;
    File file;
    int totalLength;
    private Context mContext;
    private FFmpegFrameFilter filter;

    VideoProcessing(Context context, String path) {
        mContext = context;
        file = new File(path);
        VIDEO_GRABBER = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(file);
        myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/_Pikky-Edited-Video/");
        Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "VIDEO PROCESSING PATH: " + myDirectory);

        if (!myDirectory.exists()) { myDirectory.mkdirs(); }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "DO IN BACKGROUND: " + params);
        Frame tempVideoFrame;
        try {
            VIDEO_GRABBER.start();
            initVideoRecorder(myDirectory + "/video" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");
            filter.start();
            while (VIDEO_GRABBER.grab() != null) {
                tempVideoFrame = VIDEO_GRABBER.grabImage();
                if (tempVideoFrame != null) {
                    filter.push(tempVideoFrame);
                    tempVideoFrame = filter.pull();
                    videoRecorder.record(tempVideoFrame);
                }
            }
            filter.stop();
            videoRecorder.stop();
            videoRecorder.release();
            VIDEO_GRABBER.stop();
            VIDEO_GRABBER.release();

            Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "VIDEO GRABBER STOP");

        } catch (FrameGrabber.Exception | FrameRecorder.Exception | FrameFilter.Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "ON POST EXECUTED: " + o);
    }


    private void initVideoRecorder(String path) {
        try {
            // FFmpeg effect/filter that will be applied
            filter = new FFmpegFrameFilter("colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131", VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageWidth(), VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageHeight());
            videoRecorder = FFmpegFrameRecorder.createDefault(path, VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageWidth(), VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageHeight());
            videoRecorder.start();
            Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "VIDEO PROCESSING - VIDEO RECORDER START");

        } catch (FrameRecorder.Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

This class gets called in a switch case from my **EditVideo** activity as follows - where **surfaceView** is a custom **GLSurfaceView**:

```
 case 2: surfaceView.init(mediaPlayer, new InvertColorsEffect());
                            new VideoProcessing(EditVideo.this, Configurations.videoToShareURL);
                        break;
```

Anyway, it seems that the `doInBackground` function doesn't get called anywhere, since the app only creates the custom folder in my **Pictures** directory (*_Pikky-Edited-Video*), prints its path in the Logcat - see `Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "VIDEO PROCESSING PATH: " + myDirectory);` and that's it, the video preview keeps playing in my Activity - that's because I've set my MediaPlayer's looping as true - but the other functions of my `VideoProcessing` class don't get called, `initVideoRecorder()` either.

This is my build.gradle, all necessary dependencies have been downloaded:

```
    implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.1'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.0.0-1.1', classifier: 'android-arm'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.8.1-1.1', classifier: 'android-arm'
```

I am open also to slternative solutions to render a video with filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

I've found this awesome and easy to implement framework: https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android

Just add its dependency in **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
        // jCenter
        implementation 'com.daasuu:Mp4Composer-android:0.1.6'
    }
```

And use this code to export your filtered video based on each effect:

```
renderVideoIntoMp4(myVideoURL, new GlInvertFilter()); // add the Filter you want


void renderVideoIntoMp4(String filePath, GlFilter filter) {
    tempVideoPath = getVideoFilePath();
            //Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + "/temp_video.mp4";

    new Mp4Composer(filePath, tempVideoPath)
            // .rotation(Rotation.ROTATION_270)
            //.size(720, 1280)
            .fillMode(FillMode.PRESERVE_ASPECT_FIT)
            .filter(filter)
            .mute(false)
            .flipHorizontal(false)
            .flipVertical(false)
            .listener(new Mp4Composer.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(double progress) {
                    Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "SAVING PROGRESS: " + progress);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "onCompleted()");
                    exportMp4ToGallery(getApplicationContext(), tempVideoPath);
                    Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "SAVED VIDEO PATH: " + tempVideoPath);

                    File file = new File(tempVideoPath);
                    file.delete();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCanceled() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailed(Exception e) {
                    Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "onFailed(): " + e.getMessage());
                }
            })
            .start();
}

public static void exportMp4ToGallery(Context context, String filePath) {
    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, filePath);
    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            values);
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
            Uri.parse("file://" + filePath)));
}

public File getAndroidMoviesFolder() {
    return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
}

public String getVideoFilePath() {
    return getAndroidMoviesFolder().getAbsolutePath() + "/temp_video.mp4";
}
```

Comment: Perfect - but without the "File file = new File(tempVideoPath); file.delete();"